# Display and change active keymap

Tags: windows, emacs, keyboard, vdi

I have a very complex setup:

- German keyboard
- Windows laptop
- Through VDI web client to a windows machine
- To an emacs running on VDI

All tools in the Windows VDI see the correct keymap, but my emacs does not. I am not talking about key bindings (yet, that will be the next problem). I am talking about the simple keypresses: I press a `z` and emacs sees a `y`

What puzzles me is that emacs is the only tool with this problem: it seems it does not recognize the selected keymap in the windows vdi.

How can I check what keymap is active in emacs? How can I change it?

I am **NOT** talking about key bindings.

Comment: Do you use vanilla Emacs (try launching with `emacs -Q`)? Which version? Do you experience this issue in all modes? Active keymap normally defined by the currently active major-mode. (I assume you probably tried looking into `C-h b`, `C-h m`). If that's something non-common, there's also always `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Y.E.`C-h b` show the current bindings, which is not what I want to know. I want to know what keymap is loaded: that is a level below keybindings. Emacs does not even recognize my key presses correctly. How can I show the active keymap? Ideally I would see a graphical representation of my keyboard on screen, but failing that, any other way of displaying the active keymap (**not keybindings**) would be good for me.

Comment: There are *many* keymaps simultaneously active at nearly all times in Emacs.  Not just one.  See https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs for a good overview of the keymap system.